# Is the cd command temporary?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, cd

Attempting to change my working directory...

In the command prompt, my input was:
cd F:

Command prompt returned:
F:\

Then another line appeared, reverting my working directory back to:
C:\Users\caden

Ultimately, I need to run the following command using FFmpeg, but I need to either change the current/working directory, or perhaps combine 'cd F:' with my command, I suppose...

The ffmpeg command I'm using to cut video:
ffmpeg.exe -i "F:\output" -ss 00:00:01 -t 10:00:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy GENTLEWAVESFINAL.mp4

I'm attempting to move my working/current directory, yet to no avail... I Suppose the questions I need answered are:

1. Does the command: cd change the current directory until it is altered again, or does it need to be inserted/used for each command used in the prompt?
2. If so, then that means I would need to use cd F:\ + other code - how should the combined code look, using the commands above?

Comment: To change to drive f: you simply type F: and press enter. To go to root of a drive type cd \ and press enter.

Comment: I guess it should be closed as a typo, but I don't have that privilege

Comment: the `/d` switch allows the drive to also be changed

Answer (score 1):

Usually the change is not temporary. It is permanent till next `cd`/`pushd`/`popd`.

`F:` changes current drive to `F:`

`cd F:\` changes current path on drive `F:` to root (`\`), does not change current drive

`cd \folder` changes current drive path to folder `folder` at the top of the hierarchy

`cd folder` changes current drive path to subfolder `folder` in current folder

`cd /d C:\Windows` changes current drive and folder to `C:` and `\Windows` respectively

`cd ..` changes current folder one level up

`cd \` changes current folder to root (`\`) on current drive

Answering the questions:

1. It is used once for one folder, but command `pushd` or `popd` may change this current folder.
2. Look above for my explanations.